# Python - Syntax error on Print Function 2.7

Tags: python, syntax, printing

For some background, I have been programming for many years, but never really touched Python until now, I am unsure of what is going wrong here, IDLE is flagging line 24 (last line):

```
'''
 Test Cases
'''
balance = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04

'''
 Variables
'''
previousBalance = 0
monthlyInterestRate = 0
minMonthlyPayment = 0
totalPaid = 0

m = 1
while (m != 12):
    monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12
    minMonthlyPayment = monthlyPaymentRate * previousBalance
    balance = (previousBalance - minMonthlyPayment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)
    totalPaid = totalPaid + minMonthlyPayment
    previousBalance = balance
    m += 1
print('Month: ' + str(m))
print('Minimum monthly payment: ' + str(minMonthlyPayment))
print('Total paid: ' + str(round(totalPaid, 2))
print('Remaining balance: ' + str(round(balance, 2)) #Flagging Here
```

If anyone has any ideas on why the last print function would be causing any issues, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out a parentheses at the end of line 23.

Comment: Well aren't I just the smartest little thing I have ever seen. Thanks -_- I feel like an idiot

Comment: @JuniperAsh: It's kinda hard to get used to--the interpreter keeps eating up lines until it runs into something it can't parse. If you have a syntax error, the first place you should look is the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, next time don't put parentheses around print function in 2.7. It doesn't work as efficiently. It also clears up confusion like this, I would know because it happens to me all the time. However, you should do it in 3.x.

Comment: if I remove (), then print throws syntax error. it thinks program is python3